# What is the best way to make Async Rest call from VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a rest call [post/get] from excel macro from background . The macro should execute silently for every 5sec.  If rest call gets valid response, show some message to user.
Note: When macro is running in the background Async , it should not interrupt the user experience on excel
I have used call back method, but the problem is excel is slow as the macro which makes rest call runs continuously at the background. Below is the code FYR.

```
'MyReadyStateHandler class module
Sub OnReadyStateChange()    
DoEvents    
If Actions.docx.readyState = 4 Then    
If Actions.docx.Status = 200 Then    
IsReadyState = True    
outPutText = Actions.docx.responseText    
Exit Sub     
Else     
IsReadyState = False    
Exit Sub    
End If    
End If    
End Sub    
_________________________
'Sub using MyReadyStateHandler
Public sub TestRestServiceStatus()   
Set MyOnReadyStateWrapper = New MyReadyStateHandler    
Set docx = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60    
docx.OnReadyStateChange = MyOnReadyStateWrapper    
docx.Open "POST", urlString, False    
docx.send jsonBody    
responceStatus = MyOnReadyStateWrapper.IsReadyState     
If (responceStatus = True) Then    
Dim notificationOutPut As String 
notificationOutPut=MyOnReadyStateWrapper.outPutText    
If InStr(notificationOutPut , "PROCESSING") > 0 Then    
Call TestRestServiceStatus    
ElseIf  InStr(notificationOutPut , "COMPLETE") > 0 Then    
'Notify User on Excel    
EndIF    
EndIf    
End sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code, properly formatted.  The code you show in the image is **not** VBA and nobody is going to copy it out by hand for you.

Comment: I just want to show the ref that i used,, so attached the image.. Anyways, I edited now.. Thanks

Comment: You are going to crash Excel if you do this.  When you call a Sub from itself it does not simply restart but instead adds to the stack and you will quickly run out of stack space.  Furthermore the section where you notify the user will run for each instance of the Sub in the stack.

Comment: ok,, Then any light on how can we do this ,, Is this possible with VBA or not?

Comment: For repetead run use `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "TestRestServiceStatus"` somewhere at the finishing phase of the sub so the system will start the sub over and over again. (And you need to stop this loop somehow...)  And you should destroy `MyReadyStateHandler` objects somewhere as you're gonna construct 720/hour.